# Formatting Neo4J-Shell cypher query results?

Tags: shell, neo4j, cypher, export-to-csv

Is there an option to export the results of a Neo4J-Shell cypher query in a comma-separated-value format, i.e. instead of

```
echo "START n=node(*)  MATCH n-[r]->m  RETURN n.value, type(r), m.value  ORDER BY n.value, type(r), m.value;"  |  neo4j-shell -v  -path neo4j-database/   >  /tmp/output.csv

less  /tmp/output.csv
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| n.value                                                 | type(r)                                           | m.value                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa" | "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type" | "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"                         |
| "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa" | "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"      | "Rosa"                                                        |
| "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa" | "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf" | "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#NamedPizza" |
...
```

i would like to get the following output

```
less  /tmp/output.csv

"http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa", "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type", "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"                        
"http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label", "Rosa"                                                        
"http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Rosa", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf", "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#NamedPizza" 
...
```

like in MySQL, where the ascii table is omitted when the client is used by an echo command from the shell.

Comment: You can use neoclipse for this. You can export in csv, json or xml formats.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [neo4j-JDBC](https://github.com/rickardoberg/neo4j-jdbc) to run your cypher queries via JDBC. With that in place you can use any JBCD tool that allows you to create csv.
2. Use the groovy script from https://gist.github.com/5736410